# Sitecore Media Upload creating new user sesssion

Tags: asp.net, .net, sitecore

We have limit on number of concurrent sitecore users. We are facing a unique issue, where sitecore is creating a new session when user is trying to upload an image from Medial Library. Due to this we are reaching our license limit quickly and someone has to manually kick user session using sitecore/shell/Applications/Login/Users/kick.aspx page.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

We are using Sitecore 6.4.1

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been here too. This is a known issue fixed in CMS 6.4.1 rev. 110928 (6.4.1 Update-4). :

"Multi-browser support
[Firefox, Chrome and Safari] When using the Flash-based upload, a new Sitecore user session would be registered for each upload, causing the number of concurrent user sessions to grow unexpectedly. (344158)"

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx

As the issue is with the flash-based uploader, the quick work-around is to enable the classic media uploader instead which will not invoke a new session.

In web.config :

```
      <!--  UPLOAD CLASSIC
        Indicates if uploading runs in classic (no flash) mode.
        Default: false
      -->
      <setting name="Upload.Classic" value="true" />
```

Comment: We have contacted Sitecore and they came back with same answer. Thanks for your help.